# SSIS Send email to different recipients with different data from SQL Table

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to create an `SSIS Package` that sends out emails to different recipients and includes some of the data as a table that is either included in the body of the email or attached as an Excel file.

I have three tables, one that includes the email addresses, one that includes the error type and the main table that contains customer information like name, old address info, and new address info all broken out into about 16 different columns, of which are codes to pull from the two other tables to determine which person to email to update the address and a code description on why they need to update it.

I have created a script task to combine the data and pass it to a foreach loop container.

I'm not sure how to take the customer info, old address and new address columns of data from what I've pulled together in the sql task (CIF_Nbr to Current_XIPplus4) and create a table from it that can be inserted into the body or added as an attachment to the send mail task.

A branch could have multiple lines of data so I would prefer one attachment for all same branches sent only once to that branch.

My three tables have the following columns:

[image: Customer_Info table]

[image: Branch_Email table]

[image: Return_Mail_Code Table]

[image: Combined SQL Task table]

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 and SQL server 2008 if that helps.  I'm pretty much stuck with the default toolbox.

Hopefully this all makes sense.  I'm fairly new to visual studio so the more detail the better.  Thanks.

Comment: Please show your table schema as a code snippet and not as screenshots.

Comment: Here's one example of sending data in an email https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35263/how-to-include-the-value-of-the-query-parameter-in-the-email-body-using-sp-send You can do what you want by repeatedly calling  msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail. You don't even need SSIS for this.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to take this a different direction since this was being used on more of an adhoc basis. 
Instead of SSIS I set it up in excel using power query to pull the data together from different sources and some vba code found at Ron Debruin's site http://www.rondebruin.nl/ to parse out and email each group needing to make an update.

Thanks to all for the help provided.
Let me know if you have any questions.